# annihilating matrices share an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for a simple proof (not using the proof of the much more powerful result of D. Shemesh from 1984) that a pair of complex square matrices ($n>0$) $A,B$ such that $AB=0$ must share an eigenvector. Can one deduce that $B$ must be nilpotent? I am trying to divide into two cases: when $B$ has a zero eigenvalue, and when it does not. Thanks!

Comment: It's a cool question and I don't know how to tackle it right away, but $B$ can certainly not be deduced to be nilpotent (for example if $A=0$, $B$ can be anything.) What did you try so far? Maybe Jordan normal form helps, since you have $\operatorname{im}B \subset \operatorname{ker} A$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, one must assume that the matrices are square and of nonzero size, otherwise the result is false. I'll assume you forgot to mention these hypotheses.

Then the result is obvious if either of $A,B$ is zero, since then one can just take eny eigenvector for the other one. Assume neither matrix is zero.

Now $AB=0$ means the image of $B$ is contained in the kernel of $A$, which is therefore of positive dimension. Therefore the restriction of $B$ to the kernel of $A$ has an eigenvector, which does the job.

Of course neither $A$ not $B$ needs to be nilpotent, they could for instance be the projections onto a pair of complementary subspaces.

Comment: thank you, but the restriction of B to $kerA$ has an eigenvector to which eigenvalue? And isn't $Bv$ an eigenvector for $A$ with the null eigenvalue?

Comment: I don't know for which eigenvalue the restriction of $B$ has an eigenvalue. But any linear operator on a f.d. complex vector space of positive dimension has _some_ eigenvalue. As for $Bv$, I don't know what $v$ is, but provided that $Bv\neq0$, it is indeed an eigenvector for$~A$ with eigenvalue$~0$ (as $ABv=0$).